# Keras custom loss function TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, typeerror, loss-function

I am attempting to make a custom loss function for a Keras neural network. The network has been tested and works until I attempt to use my new function. Below is the custom loss function.

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
        
    val = tf.stack([y_true, y_pred], axis=1)
    loss = tf.map_fn(fn=_apply_custom_function, elems=val)
    loss = tf.squeeze(loss)

    return loss


def _apply_custom_function(a):

    tol = 0.1
    true = a[0]
    pred = a[1]
    
    delta = pred - true
    ref = tol * abs(true)
    print(delta)
    print(ref)

    loss = tf.case([(tf.less(tf.abs(delta), ref), lambda: tf.multiply(0.1, tf.abs(delta))),
                    (tf.less(delta, tf.negative(ref)), lambda: tf.multiply(-600, tf.add(delta, ref))),
                    (tf.greater(delta, ref), lambda: tf.add(120000, tf.multiply(0.1, tf.subtract(delta, ref))))],
                   default=lambda: tf.constant([-1.]), exclusive=True)  # only one condition can be true at a time

    return loss
```

The function is called here:

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_loss_function, metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

When I run my program I get the following output:

```
Epoch 1/20
Tensor("custom_loss_function/map/while/sub:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("custom_loss_function/map/while/mul:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2825, in variable_creator_scope
    yield
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:
    C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:/Users/tester/Documents/0NEW_ANN/Create_many_single_models_V3.1_custom_loss.py:47 custom_loss_function  *
        loss = tf.map_fn(fn=_apply_custom_function, elems=val)
    C:/Users/tester/Documents/0NEW_ANN/Create_many_single_models_V3.1_custom_loss.py:72 _apply_custom_function  *
        loss = tf.case([(tf.less(tf.abs(delta), ref), lambda: tf.multiply(0.1, tf.abs(delta))),
    C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:518 multiply
        return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
    C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:6077 mul
        "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
    C:\Users\tester\Documents\0NEW_ANN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:558 _apply_op_helper
        inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

I cannot find where or how argument x becomes an int32. As you can see *delta* is printed as a float32 prior to running the first case statement. I have attempted to explicitly cast both of these as float32 and the int32 still remains. I also tried to instantiate a (1,) tensor of float32 for the constant and produced the same exact error. See that in the snippet below.

```
const1 = tf.constant([0.1], dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.case([(tf.less(tf.abs(delta), ref), lambda: tf.multiply(const1, tf.abs(delta))),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The exact line might be misleading, this happens sometimes with multi-line statements. I could imagine that the `-600` is problematic, maybe replace it with `-600.` to turn it into a float?

Comment: @xdurch0 You are correct, a simple fix. Thank you. A good lesson for multi-line statements.